# Change Background Color of Panel pro-grammatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have four panels and in each click events I have loaded different User controls. So when I click a particular panel I want the clicked panel background changed and rest panel to be same.

How can I do it pro-grammatically?

Comment: The `BackColor` is the property you want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx ; and please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what's your current code and where are you getting struck in doing that?

Comment: when  a panel is clicked i want it's back color  to red and when another panel is clicked i want previous panel back color to white and current panel to red...i want to do this with all the four panels.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Panel pan1 = new Panel();
    Panel pan2 = new Panel();
    Panel pan3 = new Panel();
    Panel pan4 = new Panel();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pan1.Name = "pan1";
        pan1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        pan1.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        pan1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        pan1.Click += new EventHandler(this.Panel_Click);

        pan2.Name = "pan2";
        pan2.Location = new Point(110, 0);
        pan2.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        pan2.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        pan2.Click += new EventHandler(this.Panel_Click);

        pan3.Name = "pan3";
        pan3.Location = new Point(220, 0);
        pan3.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        pan3.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        pan3.Click += new EventHandler(this.Panel_Click);

        pan4.Name = "pan4";
        pan4.Location = new Point(330, 0);
        pan4.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        pan4.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        pan4.Click += new EventHandler(this.Panel_Click);

        this.Controls.Add(pan1);
        this.Controls.Add(pan2);
        this.Controls.Add(pan3);
        this.Controls.Add(pan4);
    }

    private void Panel_Click(object sender , EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pan1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        this.pan2.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        this.pan3.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        this.pan4.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        Panel pan = (Panel)sender;
        pan.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```